# How can I use javascript npm in angular 6 project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular6

I am new to Angular 6 and I do not know how to use `npm i d3-dtree` in Angular 6.
How can I use Javascript libraries using `npm`, especially for Angular 6?

I want to create family-tree like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rha8sg79/) using `d3-dtree`.
Can anyone give me guide or demo how to use `d3-dtree` with `npm` in StackBlitz's link?

Comment: Your question isn't specific enough. There numerous potential questions that could be inferred from it, can you provide a specific example of how you are using `d3-dtree` and how it didn't work? The obvious answer would be trivial but unhelpful. Also, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For angular, Go inside the project and run `npm install d3 angular-d3-tree`
Then add the module in `import` array in `app.module.ts`.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-tree

For more details go to https://github.com/jgpATs2w/angular-d3-tree

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can now understand `npm` as library installer. It definitely does more than that, e.g., it can serve web pages, but think it in that way for now...

I had used plain Javascript for a long time in `.html` files. So it was very difficult for me to get used to how modern Javascript family works these days. For example, you do not need HTTP server to place `.html` files and serve web pages.

So start your Angular project in a server device using [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) which is supported by `npm`. Then in your project folder, do `npm i d3-dtree` and install the library. You can import and use the library in a different way as you did inside `.html` files in old fashion.